# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." error in ms access, i did all the troubleshooting suggested

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

i get the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." in a query.

Like this the query works perfectly

```
WorkingDays([ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE],[OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE]) AS
BOOKING_DAYS, IIf([BOOKING_DAYS]>8,"IS LATE","ON TIME") AS BOOKING_DELAYED
FROM JOB INNER JOIN [ORDER] ON JOB.[JOB_ID] = ORDER.[JOB_ID]
WHERE (((ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE) Is Not Null) AND
((ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE) Is Not Null));
```

when i try to put another criteria it shows me the error:

```
WorkingDays([ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE],[ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE]) AS 
BOOKING_DAYS, IIf([BOOKING_DAYS]>8,"IS LATE","ON TIME") AS BOOKING_DELAYED
FROM JOB INNER JOIN [ORDER] ON JOB.[JOB_ID] = ORDER.[JOB_ID]
WHERE (((ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE) Is Not Null) AND 
((ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE) Is Not Null) AND
((WorkingDays([ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE],
[ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE]))>8));
```

WorkingDays returns an integer, i tried most of the solutions proposed in other posts.

this is WorkingDays:

```
Public Function WorkingDays(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Integer
'....................................................................
' Name:     WorkingDays
' Inputs:   StartDate As Date
'   EndDate As Date
' Returns: Integer
' Author: Arvin Meyer
' Date:     February 19, 1997
' Comment: Accepts two dates and returns the number of weekdays between them
' Note that this function does not account for holidays.
'....................................................................
On Error GoTo Err_WorkingDays

Dim intCount As Integer



intCount = 0
Do While StartDate <= EndDate
'Make the above < and not <= to not count the EndDate

Select Case Weekday(StartDate)
Case Is = 1, 7
intCount = intCount
Case Is = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
intCount = intCount + 1
End Select
StartDate = StartDate + 1  
Loop
WorkingDays = intCount

Exit_WorkingDays:
Exit Function

Err_WorkingDays:
Select Case Err

Case Else
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_WorkingDays
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: `WorkingDays()` is not a standard function, please add the function code to your question.

Comment: Order is a reserved word and a SQL command. Even if not causing this problem , it will trip you up somewhere further down the line, I would strongly recommend changing that table name to something else. tblOrders ?

Comment: Andre sorry, i added WorkingDays now, Minty i can not change the table name unfortunatley, it already gave me troubles

Comment: It could be that even though you have e.g. `((ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE) Is Not Null)` in the WHERE clause, that the function is still called for NULL values. Try saving your first query, and then create a second query based on the first one, and apply `WHERE WorkingDays(...) > 8` there.

Comment: The first query is just the second query without the part that is causing me trouble

Comment: Yes. Separating the two queries tries to avoid calling the function for NULL values.

Comment: @Andre Separating the queries to filter out nulls first may not be sufficient, since the optimizer might merge the queries again in a way that still causes this error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44804170/7296893) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using `Is Not Null` and a function that can't handle Null values in the same query.

While you may assume this could work just fine, as the Null values get filtered out, they still get passed to this function and create an error.

Use `Nz` to escape the nulls getting passed to the function:

```
WorkingDays(Nz([ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE], 0),Nz([ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE], 0)) AS 
BOOKING_DAYS, IIf([BOOKING_DAYS]>8,"IS LATE","ON TIME") AS BOOKING_DELAYED
FROM JOB INNER JOIN [ORDER] ON JOB.[JOB_ID] = ORDER.[JOB_ID]
WHERE (((ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE) Is Not Null) AND 
((ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE) Is Not Null) AND
((WorkingDays(Nz([ORDER.ORDER_NOTIFICATION_DATE], 0),
Nz([ORDER.OP_DISTRIBUTION_DATE], 0)))>8));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and knowing 'Nz' is very useful